# How do I write a unit test for a function that returns multiple values from a set of mappings?

Tags: mapping, unittesting

The getData function fetch the stored data:

```
function getData(string memory _idNumber)
    public
    view
    returns (
        string memory,
        string memory,
        uint256
    )
{
    return (
        idNumberToName[_idNumber],
        idNumberToEmail[_idNumber],
        idNumberToAmount[_idNumber]
    );
}
```

My goal is to test the getData function to verify the mappings have no data, no luck so far. This is my idea how to test the getData function:

```
it("The mappings should be empty", async function () {
    const idNumber = ""

    const currentIdNumberToName = await dataStorage.getData(idNumber)
    const currentIdNumberToEmail = await dataStorage.getData(idNumber)
    const currentIdNumberToAmount = await dataStorage.getData(idNumber)

    const expectedIdNumberToName = ""
    const expectedIdNumberToEmail = ""
    const expectedIdNumberToAmount = "0"

    assert.equal(expectedIdNumberToName, currentIdNumberToName)
    assert.equal(expectedIdNumberToEmail, currentIdNumberToEmail)
    assert.equal(
        expectedIdNumberToAmount,
        currentIdNumberToAmount.toString()
    )
})
```

Comment: What are you using web3js or ethers.js? It should return a tuple or a dictionary.

Comment: @Ismael I wrote the test with ethers.js. I think my mistake is in how I'm calling the currentIdNumberToName, currentIdNumberToEmail and currentIdNumberToAmount in the test script. As you can see in the script I'm calling the function three times to get the values, but in my contract the function is called only once, but I don't know how to do same in the test.

Comment: @Ismael, answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73604344/19627240)

Comment: That should work, I'd prefer their second solution `const [currentIdNumberToName,currentIdNumberToEmail,currentIdNumberToAmount] = 
      await dataStorage.getData(idNumber)`, so you will be making 1 call to `dataStorage.getData` instead of 3. Please, add your answer as solution so the question can be marked as resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
it("The mappings should be empty", async function () {
    const idNumber = ""

   const [currentIdNumberToName,currentIdNumberToEmail,currentIdNumberToAmount] = 
      await dataStorage.getData(idNumber)
    
    const expectedIdNumberToName = ""
    const expectedIdNumberToEmail = ""
    const expectedIdNumberToAmount = "0"

    assert.equal(expectedIdNumberToName, currentIdNumberToName)
    assert.equal(expectedIdNumberToEmail, currentIdNumberToEmail)
    assert.equal(
        expectedIdNumberToAmount,
        currentIdNumberToAmount.toString()
    )
})
```